# Invoking PolicyKit/polkit via xinit/startx?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, x11, authentication, polkit

I recently upgraded a minimal installation of Ubuntu (with no full-fledged DE) from precise to saucy and since doing so I'm no longer able to mount removable drives as a normal user. I googled a bit and found it's something related to policykit... but I can't find any example of how to invoke policykit in an .xinitrc file, i.e., without using a display manager. Also, the Ubuntu repos have the following packages:

```
lxpolkit
policykit-1
policykit-1-gnome
policykit-desktop-privileges
```

and they each have similar descriptions, so I'm not even sure which of them I should install.

Does anyone using startx/xinit to start X have a working config with policykit and/or instructions they can share?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to launch policykit in your X session, you may add the following line in your home/user/.xinitrc

```
 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
```

When lauching the startx command, this should start the policykit daemon directly with your X session.